# How to copy files to desktop for every language?

Tags: bash

My bash script should copy files from `/opt/test/file.txt` to the user's Desktop.
The source path is always the same, but how do I copy to desktop? The desktop has a different name in every language...

in German it is for example: cd `$HOME/Arbeitsfläche` and not `$HOME/Desktop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User directories are defined in a parsable file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. To get the value set for a different locale our script may have to import these variables.

Example:

```
source ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
echo $XDG_DESKTOP_DIR
```

Also see: [Freedesktop.org Wiki](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/)